# Splitting a column to create new columns when the number of elements varies a lot

Tags: python, pyspark, split

I have a dataframe df and a column LongColumn that that has rows like this:

```
FIRST_WORD.ABC.approved.Address.Street.Phone.Email.Category1.Beta.MyResults.New
FIRST_WORD.DEF.Address.Street.Phone.Email.Category2.Alpha.MyResults.New
FIRST_WORD.ABC.Address.Street.Phone.Email.Category6.Gamma.MyResults.New
FIRST_WORD.GHI.approved.Address.Street.Phone.Email.Category1.Alpha.MyResults.New
```

I did the following to split and create new columns:

```
out_df=df.withColumn('LongColumn', F.split('LongColumn', '\.')).withColumn('Category', F.expr('LongColumn[size(LongColumn) - 4]')).withColumn('Letter', F.expr('LongColumn[size(LongColumn) - 3]')).withColumn('dataset', F.expr('LongColumn[size(LongColumn) - 2]'))
```

But I need two extra columns: `Status` which contains `approved` if the word `approved` appears there, and `unapproved` if it does not , and `Code` which contains the three letters on the second position.

The three latin letters are always on the same position (if I take it top-down), but no matter the direction, the `approved` is a problem. Is it possible to solve this similarly or do I need to modify the dataset?

Expected output (assuming I drop the `LongColumn` whose values are now arrays):

```
Code     Status        Category     Letter     dataset
ABC      approved      Category1    Beta       MyResults
DEF      unapproved    Category2    Alpha      MyResults
ABC      unapproved    Category6    Gamma      MyResults
GHI      approved      Category1    Alpha      MyResults
```

Comment: Would you be able to post an expected output?

Comment: @EmiOB posted, hopefully with no typos. Thank you!

Comment: @EmiOB I was thinking of just putting an IF condition: and do the split based on whether the string contains "approved" or not.

Comment: that would be how I would think to do it, was waiting to see if someone else knew a smart way to do it first though

Comment: @Emi OB In that case, does it mean we have to iterate through every row and check? Alternatively, I was thinking of just writing a dataset with "approved" and one with "unapproved", and then unioning them, but it does not seem more efficient.

Comment: @jonnydoe I would look up how to check if a substring exists with in pandas column, iterating through pandas columns is frowned upon, so there will be a better way, or could be done using .apply()

Comment: @johnnydoe

what is the Spark version you use?

I do have solution for Spark >=3.1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IMP Note
Spark version >=3.1
```

```
Solution
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data=[("FIRST_WORD.ABC.approved.Address.Street.Phone.Email.Category1.Beta.MyResults.New",),
("FIRST_WORD.DEF.Address.Street.Phone.Email.Category2.Alpha.MyResults.New",),
("FIRST_WORD.ABC.Address.Street.Phone.Email.Category6.Gamma.MyResults.New",),
("FIRST_WORD.GHI.approved.Address.Street.Phone.Email.Category1.Alpha.MyResults.New",)]
schema=["LongColumn"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
out_df=df.withColumn('LongColumn', F.split('LongColumn', '\.'))\
.withColumn('Category', F.expr('LongColumn[size(LongColumn) - 4]'))\
.withColumn('Letter', F.expr('LongColumn[size(LongColumn) - 3]'))\
.withColumn('dataset', F.expr('LongColumn[size(LongColumn) - 2]'))\
.withColumn('status_val',F.array(F.lit("approved"),F.lit("unapproved")))\
.withColumn("status",F.filter("LongColumn",lambda x:F.array_contains("status_val",x)))\
.withColumn("status",F.when(F.size(F.col("status"))==1,F.col("status")[0]).otherwise(F.lit("unapproved")))\
.drop("status_val")
out_df.show(10,0)

output
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+
|LongColumn                                                                                  |Category |Letter|dataset  |status    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+
|[FIRST_WORD, ABC, approved, Address, Street, Phone, Email, Category1, Beta, MyResults, New] |Category1|Beta  |MyResults|approved  |
|[FIRST_WORD, DEF, Address, Street, Phone, Email, Category2, Alpha, MyResults, New]          |Category2|Alpha |MyResults|unapproved|
|[FIRST_WORD, ABC, Address, Street, Phone, Email, Category6, Gamma, MyResults, New]          |Category6|Gamma |MyResults|unapproved|
|[FIRST_WORD, GHI, approved, Address, Street, Phone, Email, Category1, Alpha, MyResults, New]|Category1|Alpha |MyResults|approved  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+

Do let me know if you have any questions around the same.

kindly upvote if you like my Solution
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'pyspark.sql.functions' has no attribute 'filter' :( Is it because of my version?

Comment: In my error it says [module version: 1.420.0]

Comment: Please use the version 3.1 or more than that

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.filter.html

Comment: Thank you! Just one short question, if I wanted a column that contained "Phone.Email.Category1" etc., so a part of the string, dots included, I do no longer need to make an array, right?

Comment: @johnnydoe

that purely depends what you want to have for the above mentioned as output .
if you shed some light . i am happy to help

Comment: thank you, I did it by setting the delimiter as a certain word from the string, and take everything that comes after it.